# Exporting only certain fields from a PostGIS table using QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, python, postgis

I'm trying to export tables from a PostGIS database into MapInfo TAB files, but only certain rows and columns. I have my rows exporting right, using a query, but I'm stuck on just getting the columns I'm interested in. I thought the

request.setSubsetOfAttributes(["obj","name","railway"],vlayer.pendingFields())

below would do the trick, but I'm still getting all of the original fields in my output.

```
    if table == "line_table":
        fields = vlayer.pendingFields()

        railway = ["Railway", r""""railway" != ''"""]
        request = QgsFeatureRequest()
        request.setFilterExpression(railway[1])
                   request.setSubsetOfAttributes(["obj","name","railway"],vlayer.pendingFields())

        selectedFeatures = vlayer.getFeatures(request)

        selectedRows = []  
        for feature in selectedFeatures:
           selectedRows.append(feature.id())

        vlayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectedRows)

        output = outputBase + "/" + railway[0] + "_" + database + ".tab"

        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, output, encoding, coordsys, "MapInfo File", True)
        print "Translation of " + railway[0] + "_" + database + ".tab successful."
```

Comment: vlayer is not affected by vlayer.getFeatures(request) iterator generator other than in the for loop... more, the QgsVectorFileWirter is not affected by request and OGR available option does not allow sub selection of fields: http://qgis.org/api/qgsvectorfilewriter_8cpp_source.html#l00653 => I suggest you to create a temporary memory layer and then wirte the shape.... btw it's really simple to add this feature to QgsVectorFileWriter passing the request and manage it here: http://qgis.org/api/qgsvectorfilewriter_8cpp_source.html#l01896

Answer (score 1):

Using comment by @LuigiPirelli, I did end up getting it to work by using a memory layer with just the fields I wanted, then populating those fields with the values in the original table.

```
    if table == "line_table":
        fields = vlayer.pendingFields()

        railway = ["Railway", r""""railway" != ''"""]
        request = QgsFeatureRequest()
        request.setFilterExpression(railway[1])

        rails = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs=epsg:3395", "rails", "memory")
        if not rails.isValid(): raise Exception("Failed to create memory layer")
        pr = rails.dataProvider()
        rails.startEditing()
        pr.addAttributes([QgsField("name", QVariant.String),QgsField("railway", QVariant.String)])

        selectedRows = []
        selectedFeatures = vlayer.getFeatures(request)

        for feature in selectedFeatures:
            selectedRows.append(feature.id())
            newFeature = QgsFeature()
            newFeature.setGeometry(feature.geometry())
            newFeature.setAttributes([feature.attribute("name"), feature.attribute("railway")])
            pr.addFeatures([newFeature])

        rails.commitChanges()
        rails.updateExtents()
        vlayer.setSelectedFeatures(selectedRows)
        rails.setSelectedFeatures(selectedRows)
        mapLayer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rails)

        output = outputBase + "/" + database + "/" + railway[0] + ".tab"
        QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(mapLayer, output, encoding, coordsys, "MapInfo File", False)

        print "Translation of " + outputBase + database + "/" + railway[0] + ".tab successful."
```